# How to check if it is 404 error page(page does not exist) using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Here i am trying to read urls and getting the images in a page. I need to exclude the page if it is 404 and stop getting the images from a 404 error page. How to do it using HtmlAgilityPack? Here is my code

```
var document = new HtmlWeb().Load(completeurl);
var urls = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
          .Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
          .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToList();
```

Comment: You need to check the response status before you look for the images.

Comment: @jdweng is there a way to check in the document variable that this page does not exists?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to register a `PostRequestHandler` event on the `HtmlWeb` instance, it will be raised after each downloaded document and you'll get access to the `HttpWebResponse` object. It has a property for the `StatusCode`.

```
 HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
 HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
 web.PostRequestHandler += (request, response) =>
 {
     if (response != null)
     {
         statusCode = response.StatusCode;
     }
 }

 var doc = web.Load(completeUrl)
 if (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
 {
     // received a read document
 }
```

Looking at the code of the HtmlAgilityPack on GitHub, it's even simpler, `HtmlWeb` has a property `StatusCode` which is set with the value:

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var document = web.Load(completeurl);

if (web.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    var urls = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
          .Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
          .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToList();
}
```

### Update

There has been an update to the AgilityPack API. The trick is still the same:

```
var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
var lastStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

htmlWeb.PostResponse = (request, response) =>
{
    if (response != null)
    {
        lastStatusCode = response.StatusCode;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

**Be aware of the version you use!**

I am using `HtmlAgilityPack v1.5.1` and there is no `PostRequestHandler` event.

In the `v1.5.1` one has to use `PostResponse` field. See example below.

```
var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
var lastStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

htmlWeb.PostResponse = (request, response) =>
{
    if (response != null)
    {
        lastStatusCode = response.StatusCode;
    }
};
```

There are not many differences but still they are.

Hope this will save some time to someone.

Comment: @jessehouwing, good point! Hmm, anybody can propose an edit. I haven't noticed it till now) Thanks!